# centos 6 kickstart cloud

Tags: linux, cloud, centos6

I am trying to create a Kickstart script for Centos 6 that would be Cloud ready, so as a basic pre-requisite it will have just 1 partition so the cloud-init scripts will be capable of growing the partition.

While I have been successful with Centos 7, I am finding lot of issues with Centos 6.

The far I have gone is creating just 1 partition, but kickstart seems failing to make it bootable and there it breaks.

Also note I am using QUEMU + PACKER, so I got the VIRTIO drivers loaded as part of the build.

So, this has been my code so far

```
install
url --url http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/os/x86_64/
repo --name updates --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/updates/x86_64/
repo --name="os" --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/os/x86_64/ --cost=100
repo --name="updates" --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/updates/x86_64/ --cost=100
repo --name="extras" --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/extras/x86_64/ --cost=100

# for too new hardware
unsupported_hardware

text
skipx
bootloader

firewall --disabled
selinux --disabled
firstboot --disabled

lang en_GB.UTF-8
keyboard uk
timezone --utc Etc/UTC

zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part / --ondisk=vda --size=8191 --grow

rootpw password
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512


reboot

%packages --nobase
@core
-*firmware
-b43-openfwwf
-efibootmgr
-audit*
-libX*
-fontconfig
-freetype
sudo
openssh-clients
openssh-server
gcc
make
perl
kernel-firmware
kernel-devel
%end

%post
sed -i 's/^.*requiretty/#Defaults requiretty/' /etc/sudoers
sed -i 's/rhgb //' /boot/grub/grub.conf
%end
```

And I just got stuck there.
I have tried many combinations in terms of partition but nothing seems to work.

For Centos7 I do not have any of those problems, but Centos 6.9 seems harder.

Any help, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this just worked as stated below...:

```
install
url --url http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/os/x86_64/
repo --name updates --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/updates/x86_64/
repo --name="os" --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/os/x86_64/ --cost=100
repo --name="updates" --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/updates/x86_64/ --cost=100
repo --name="extras" --baseurl=http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6/extras/x86_64/ --cost=100

# for too new hardware
unsupported_hardware

text
skipx
bootloader

firewall --disabled
selinux --disabled
firstboot --disabled

lang en_GB.UTF-8
keyboard uk
timezone --utc Etc/UTC

zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part / --ondisk=vda --size=3000 --grow

rootpw password
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
```

I assume the **ondisk** was the missing bit on all this.